Ubuntu in emergency mode - able to login but unable to get into user profile
Kindly help - unable to come out of emergency mode .
mount -a  result is as follows
mount: /etc/fstab: prase error at line 14 -- ignored
[2346.136153]  /disk/by-uuid/530ac80d-026f-4a60-bdb6-3f899c754cb4: Can't lookup blockdev
mount: /home : special device /disk/by-uuid/530ac80d-026f-4a60-bdb6-3f899c754cb4 does not exist.
dmesg(1) may have more information after fauld mount system call.

Please [edit] your question and format it using a code block. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help As suggested, check the output of dmesg for errors and for information about your expected disks.

It's hard to understand what is happening due to possible typos in the question, but it seems you have fstab problems. Check line 14 in /etc/fstab and edit your question to show it.
